# Printing to Excel File From Java Based on Columns

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Apologies in advance for any formatting/other errors, I am still very much a newbie to Java.

I am conducting a gene expression analysis in which I have a program that prints ~ 6 million gene names and their expression values in 23,000 sets of 249 (there are 249 patients total and they each have 23,000 genes/gene expression values). Right now, I have this program looping through all the 249 individual patient files, obtaining the 23,000 gene values, and printing to a text file (with 6 million rows and 2 columns, one column for gene name and one for expression).

However, I would like this program to print to an excel file instead, so that there are 249 rows (for each patient) and 23,000 columns (for each gene). I have been trying for a couple of days to do this (with apache POI) and still am unable to. I found this example code: https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/01/write-excel-file-in-java.html, which is what I have been trying to modify to fit my program, but nothing seems to be working. I have included my original program (that prints to the text file but also include the POI jars I downloaded). Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcel {


   public static final File folder = new File("C:/Users/menon/OneDrive/Documents/R/TARGET");
   private static PrintStream output;
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
   XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("values");

   public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      output = new PrintStream(new File("final_CSRSEF_data.txt"));
      listFilesForFolder(folder);
   }

   public static double listFilesForFolder(final File folder) throws FileNotFoundException {
      double value = 0.0;
      //contains names of all the 23k genes in order to loop through the 249 files and collect the needed names each time
      File list = new File("C:/Users/menon/OneDrive/Documents/NamesOfGenes.txt");
      Scanner names = new Scanner(list);
      String data;
      while (names.hasNext()) {
         String name = names.next(); 
         //looping through all separate 249 patient files in folder and searching for gene name        
         for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            Scanner files = new Scanner(fileEntry);
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
               listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
               while (files.hasNextLine()) {
                  final String lineFromFile = files.nextLine();
                  if(lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
                     //System.out.print(name+ " in file " + fileEntry.getName());
                     String[] thisOne = lineFromFile.split("\\s");
                     String res = thisOne[0];
                     //System.out.println(res);
                     if (res.equals(name)) {
                        print(lineFromFile);
                        print("\n");
                     }
                  }
               }

            }
         }
         print("----------------");
         print("\n");
      }
      return 0.0;
   }

   //print to final_CSRSEF_data.txt
   private static void print(String stat) {
      output.print(stat);
   }
}
```

So basically what I am printing before the "---------------" in each text file should instead be in a separate column (not row) in an excel sheet.

Once again, thank you in advance!

Comment: "I would like this program to print to an excel file instead, so that there are 249 rows (for each patient) and 23,000 columns (for each gene)." Not possible. Even latest `Excel` versions only provide 16,384 columns max. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3: "Total number of rows and columns on a worksheet: 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns".

Comment: Alex is right,
May be there's option to rearrange the output, for example to save 23,000 rows and 249 columns

Comment: @edwigz Ok, thank you for replying. Would there be a way to split it and save it in multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

try look at this:

www.pela.it, in my home page there's a link to download "gene expression" tool

i did it in java two years ago and if it is what you are trying to do i'll be happy to help.

It elaborate an xml raw data output from pcr tool and finally print a paginated excel with all elaboration phases. There's a ppt too that explain in detail.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! I checked out your tool and it looks great, but unfortunately I'm not sure whether it will be of much use to me because I am conducting my actual analyses in R and I am using Java only to merge the datasets and get all 6 million of the values together. I would really appreciate any suggestions you have on how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ankita, i can send you my java code for excel generation, give me an email address. Or if you prefer send me source data, i will try to write a specific code for it. have a nice day :)